# External monitor not working with i915 graphics

Tags: 14.04, xrandr, external-monitor

I'm trying to make the external monitor work with the i915 driver on Kodibuntu (based on 14.04LTS) with a Lenovo Edge E320. The external monitor gets enabled during the boot, but is disabled as soon as X starts. I have added the kernel parameter i915.modeset=1 , so that now the external monitor is listed by xrandr (as VGA1), however enabling it doesn't work, the monitor stays switched off. xrandr can switch on and off the LVDS properly though.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here with Ubuntu 15.10 on a MacBook Pro 13 2011.
There is a workaround:

```
$ xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync

$ xrandr --addmode DP1 "1920x1080_60.00"
```

Then in Settings/Monitors I see the externar monitor. But this is no "plug & play". With Ubuntu 15.04 all works fine.